# apache camel and jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel

I'm trying out apache-camel, and I've set up a basic route that calls an http service via http4 component, transforms the result via unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson), and then prints out part of the response in a bean component.

The problem I'm having is that it blows up at runtime when it gets to the json unmarhsaller:

> No type converter available to convert from type: java.util.HashMap to the required type: com.xxx.MyType

The response is of this format:

```
{"data":[{"x":"y"},{"x":"z"}]}
```

And my object model is like:

```
@lombok.Data
class Response {
    private List<Elem> data;
}

@lombok.Data 
class Elem {
    private String x;
}
```

So it would appear that the unmarshaller thinks the response is a hash map, whereas I want it to unmarshal into an object structure. Is there a way to get it to do what I want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the answer, posting in case anyone else runs into this. The route builder should be setup like:

```
from("direct:start").to("http4://...").unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson,com.xxx.Response)
.to("bean:com.xxx.MyResponseEchoer")
```

I.e. pass the class type to the json method.