# Apache Camel serialize Java String/ArrayList to JSON object with jackson

Tags: json, apache, serialization

I am currently working with Apache Camel and I am creating a route in which I am parsing XML and enriching it with JSON string. So far so good. After enrichment I am joining JSON strings. First idea was to use ArrayList and the other one was to use string separated by comma. This was no problem, but I need to return JSON object which is then used by REST

Here is piece of my class:

```
public class MyBean {

private String jsonStrings;
List<String> jsonStringsArray = new ArrayList<String>();

public void addEnrichSourceToString(Exchange exchange) {
    Boolean isCompleted = (Boolean) exchange.getProperty("CamelSplitComplete");
    String incomingString = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

    this.jsonStringsArray.add(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
    this.jsonStrings += incomingString + ",";

    if (isCompleted) {
        this.jsonStrings = "{\"MyNode\": [" + this.jsonStrings.substring(4, this.jsonStrings.length() - 1) + "]}";
        exchange.getOut().setBody(this.jsonStrings);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `[apache]` tag should be replaced by `[apache-camel]`.

Answer (score -3):

I don't see any question here. If you want to know how to unmarshal to a POJO, just read the [camel json page](http://camel.apache.org/json.html). It has enough details.

Also, [see this thread on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509859/apache-camel-and-jackson)